# словарь список и цикл помогите разобраться в упражнении

Tags: python, python-3.x

Переберите список людей, которые должны участвовать в опросе. Если они уже прошли опрос, выведите сообщение с благодарностью, а если нет выведите сообщение с предложением принять участие.

Я что-то не так сделал и у меня программа повторяется (участники которые не приняли участие).

Я не давно начал изучать и некому обратится. спасибо за помощь!

Вот мой код.

```
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phill': 'python',
    }

polls = ['jen', 'sarah', 'edward', 'phill', 'nik', 'david', 'valera']

    for name in favorite_languages.keys():

print(f"{name.title()} thanks for tacking the poll!")

    for poll in polls:

         if poll not in favorite_languages.keys():

              print(f"{poll.title()}, please take the poll!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
favorite_languages = { 'jen': 'python', 'sarah': 'c', 'edward': 'ruby', 'phill': 'python'}
polls = ['jen', 'sarah', 'edward', 'phill', 'nik', 'david', 'valera']

for name in polls:
    if name in favorite_languages: #проверка, прошёл ли чел из polls опрос
        print(f"{name.title()} thanks for tacking the poll!") #если прошёл - благодарит
    else:
        print(f"{name.title()}, please take the poll!") #если не прошёл - просит пройти
```

Comment: как я запутался, спасибо тебе большое!!